# Advice on using hypervisor to run a Real Time OS in parallel with Windows/Linux

Tags: rtos, hypervisor

What are your advice/experience of using a hypervisor (e.g. [RTS Real-Time Hypervisor](http://www.real-time-systems.com/real-time_hypervisor/)) to run an RTOS in parallel with a non real time OS. Are there any performance implications? Are there any risks involved? (like how can you ensure that the non-real time OS will not interfere with the real time aspects of the RTOS)

From what I understand, a dual core (or hyperthreading) CPU has to be used so that you can assign each OS its own core.

Comment: Linux **is** a hypervisor now (since 2.6.0). See http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no, it doesn't need dual core or hyperthreading.

   - no, the non-RT tasks doesn't interfere with RT ones.

The main idea is to have one RTOS, which executes tasks written specifically for this OS, using it's own API.  These tasks are set in string priority levels, where a higher priority task will **allways** take precedence over a lower priority one.  The lowest priority tasks will execute only as long as there's no other task available to run (that is, they're all waiting for some event, either a timeout or an external signal).

all this is just like a usual multitasking OS scheduler, it doesn't need multple cores or hardware threads; it's just that the timing guarantees are radically different, and the available API reflects this fact.

In those hybrid implementations, there's a single lowest-level task that runs a full non-RT OS  kernel, usually Linux or some other unix-like kernel (i don't know about windows, but should work the same).  Nowadays, we call this architecture a hypervisor.

so, since the whole non-RT OS is run as the lowest-priority task, it doesn't have any guarantee of getting processing time at all.  any RT task can interrupt it at any time, even when accessing hardware.  to keep this, usually the RT tasks have very limited access to the  hardware, or there are minimal arbitrations at very low level. ie: can interrupt a disk access (possibly resulting in a access error); but not a PCI access (as long as are short-lived and time-bounded)

there's also some soft-RT extensions to the Linux scheduler for some time now; but the timing  guarantees aren't so tight as some hard-RT OSes built with that in mind.